# Call all classes that implement an interface

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns

I have the following code in place.

Interface Vehicle which has a method calculateDistance.

Class Car implements Vehicle
Class Bicycle implements Vehicle
Class MotorCycle implements Vehicle

What I want to do next is a method in my controller that calls every class that implements Vehicle and get the values from calculateDistance.

What would be the best way/design pattern to achieve this?

At this moment I am just calling all the classes that implement the interface Vehicle (via ReflectionClass) and loop over them to call this method.

Comment: The thing is that with designpatters you can 'try' multiple things. It's not about trying, it's about what is the most correct way of achieving this.

I can paste all the possible things I 'tried', but this would just clutter the question.

Comment: You say "I have the following code", but then don't actually show the code... you just kinda describe it. Post the code (the latest iteration). Also describe the variations you dismissed, and why you dismissed them. Is this a real-world issue or is it homework? This is quite a strange real-world requirement: "[...] a method in my controller that calls every class that implements Vehicle and get the values from calculateDistance". Why do you need to do this? ie: what do you *actually* need to achieve as an end result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to implement CompilerPass. Here is an [example](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-service-container-how-to-make-your-service-use-tags/) .
So, create a registry class (`TransportChain` class in that example), interface, and all classes that implements that interface, define them as services and give them tag name.
After that, you can call that registry service in your action, and call your desired method by each service.

Basic example:

interface

```
interface SomeInterface {
   public function doSomething();
}
```

Service 1:

```
class First implement SomeInterface {
    public function doSomething() {
        // do smth
    }
}
```

Service 2:

```
class Second implement SomeInterface {
    public function doSomething() {
        // do smth
    }
}
```

Registry class:

```
class MyRegistry
{
    private $services = [];

    public function addMyService($service)
    {
        $this->services[] = $service;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->services;
    }
}
```

CompilerPass:

```
   ...

   $myServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('my_tag');

    if (empty($myServices)) {
        return;
    }

    $registry = $container->getDefinition('my_registry');

    foreach ($myServices as $key => $myService) {
        $registry->addMethodCall('add', [new Reference($key)]);
    }

    ...
```

After clearign the cache, you can call them in your action:

```
...

foreach ($this->get('my_registry')->all() as $myService) {
    $myService->doSomething();
}

...
```

The whole other stuff, like declaring services, give them tag name, registering your compiler pass has been written [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html).